If $A$ (square matrix) is normal and all singular values are different then it is PSD?
I was not able to spot where a mistake would be in the following proof.
The SVD of $A$ is $A=U \Sigma V^* $. Therefore, $AA^* =UDU^* $ and $A^* A=VDV^* $, but $A$ is normal so $UDU^* = VDV^* = C $. Given that $A$ has different singular values, we "force" the eigenvectors in $U$ and $V$ to be equal each other since all $C$ eingespaces have dimension $1$, then $U=V$. Going back to the original SVD of $A$, we can now rewrite it as $A=U \Sigma U^* $ which clearly is a spectral decomposition. Once the singular values are non-negative , it can be concluded that $A$ is a PSD.
I suppose that there is an error because, it's known that, for normal matrices, the singular value equals the absolute of the eigenvalues. So I could choose the eigenvalues to be negative or even complex but assuring they have different modulos, which would not characterize a PSD.

no, $A = diag([1,-2])$

The eigenspaces in $U$ and $V$ are the same, but the eigenvectors may not be. For an explicit example, consider @goldboy ’s example of $\text{diag}(1, -2)$. Then you can have $U = \text{diag}(1, -1)$ and $V = \text{diag}(1, 1)$. The eigenvectors forming their columns are not the same - indeed, $(0, -1)^T \neq (0, 1)^T$. But they do span the same eigenspaces, which is what your arguments actually show. To summarize, you do have each column of $U$ is a multiple (multiplying by a scalar of modulus $1$, to be precise) of the corresponding column of $V$, but that does not mean $U = V$.

There is no such thing as "the SVD" of $A$.  It would accurate to say "an SVD of $A$" but SVD's are not unique.  Polar Decomposition on the other hand is unique for $A\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ and makes your problem somewhat obvious-- if $A=UP=PU$ where $U$ is unitary-- then is it necessarily the case that $U=I$?  Of course not, let $P$ be and $U$ be diagonal and you have many choices from there.  [Note the singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $P$ and the point about all singular values being unique is a red herring.]
